# How do I change the line drawing size in a panel?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, panel

I am using this code to draw on a panel in a WinForm using my mouse pointer.

```
public partial class Signature : Form
{
    SolidBrush color;
    List<List<Point>> _lines;
    Boolean _mouseDown;

    public Signature()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _lines = new List<List<Point>>();
        color = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
        _mouseDown = false;
    }

    private void clear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _lines.Clear();
        panel1.Invalidate();
    }

    private void panel1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        _mouseDown = true;
        _lines.Add(new List<Point>());
    }


    private void panel1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_mouseDown)
        {
            _lines.Last().Add(e.Location);
            panel1.Invalidate();

        }
    }

    private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var lineSet in _lines)
        {
            if (lineSet.Count > 1)
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawLines(new Pen(color), lineSet.ToArray());
            }
        }
    }
    private void panel1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        _mouseDown = false;
    }
}
```

}

I'm fairly new to programming, so forgive me if this is a stupid question. I have no idea how to make the line that is drawn a bit thicker. Could somebody assist me, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

instead of `new Pen(color)` you can use `new Pen(color, floatWidth)`

example can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/y7858dt5.aspx)

Comment: No worries :) you should remember msdn, its more or less a .net bible... if your ever wondering about a class, method, or anything else related to .net then just type your class/method/etc name into google followed by 'msdn'

Comment: Thanks for the advice. :) I will remember that in future.